# Помогите с кодом php WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такой код, который добавляет список постов HTML_Blocks, и по идее должен выводить выбранный пост в подменю элемента, в котором выбран пост. Но почему-то пост не выводится. Напишите пожалуйста, где я ошибся и где написанный код неверный и помогите решить проблему)

```
add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', 'add_menu_item_custom_fields', 10, 4 );

function add_menu_item_custom_fields( $item_id, $item, $depth, $args ) {
// Check if the menu item type is "post_type"
if ( 'post_type' !== $item->type ) {
    return;
}

// Get the available posts in the post type
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'HTML_Blocks',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    )
);

// If there are no available posts, do nothing
if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
    return;
}

// Create the custom field for the list of posts
?>
<p class="field-custom description description-wide">
    <label for="menu-item-post-<?php echo esc_attr( $item_id ); ?>-posts">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Select a post', 'text-domain' ); ?>
    </label>
    <select id="menu-item-post-<?php echo esc_attr( $item_id ); ?>-posts" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom" name="menu-item-post[<?php echo esc_attr( $item_id ); ?>][posts]">
        <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" <?php selected( $post->ID, $item->object_id ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $post->post_title ); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</p>
<?php
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_item_post_content', 10, 2 );

function add_menu_item_post_content( $items, $args ) {
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    // Check if the menu item type is "post_type"
    if ( 'post_type' !== $item->type ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Get the selected post ID
    $post_id = isset( $item->object_id ) ? intval( $item->object_id ) : 0;

    // If the post ID is invalid, do nothing
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Get the selected post
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // If the post is invalid, do nothing
    if ( empty( $post ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Add the post content to the menu item
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ); ?>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php
    $item->classes[] = 'has-post-content';
    $item->post_content = ob_get_clean();
}

return $items;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)